# Sorting a table in python with alphabet and numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have the following table:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 99 | QA |
| 65 | CD |
| 134 | LL |
| N12 | OO |
| 127 | KK |
| Q23 | MM |
| 1 | AA |
| A10 | KL |
| K9 | MA |

I would like to sort the table such that the numbers are sorted in descending order first then the alphabets in descending order. How do I do that? The output should look something like the following:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 134 | LL |
| 127 | KK |
| 99 | QA |
| 65 | CD |
| 1 | AA |
| Q23 | MM |
| N12 | OO |
| K9 | MA |
| A10 | KL |

Comment: assume K9 and A10 are sorted incorrectly in your example?

Comment: Are the `134,...` actual numbers or strings?

Comment: 134,... are numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
so = sorted(df.Column1, key=lambda x: (x.isnumeric(),int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x))[::-1]
```

**so:**

```
['134', '127', '99', '65', '1', 'Q23', 'N12', 'K9', 'A10']
```

The only thing I need to do is connect it with pandas query. Will update the answer shortly. Right now having trouble with syntax.

**Edit:**

```
df.set_index('Column1').loc[so, :]
```

---

```
    Column2
Column1 
134 LL
127 KK
99  QA
65  CD
1   AA
Q23 MM
N12 OO
K9  MA
A10 KL
```

This logic can be applied using `sort_values` also. But I ain't able to do that.

Comment: @Manakin I guess the logic is first part will include all the integers in descending order and second part will include string in descending order by alphabet. `Q>N>K>A`

Comment: totally missed that part, nice one.

Comment: @Manakin: I am just wondering how it can be done using `sort_values`. I get ended up with errors :'(.

Answer (score 1):

you need two sorts, one on the integers then one on the integers with letters.

we can concat the result and pass the index into your main df.

```
idx = pd.concat([
            df['Column1'].loc[~pd.to_numeric(df['Column1'],errors='coerce').isna()].astype(int).sort_values(ascending=False),
            df['Column1'].loc[pd.to_numeric(df['Column1'],errors='coerce').isna()].str.replace('\d+','').sort_values(ascending=False)]).index


print(df.loc[idx])



  Column1 Column2
2     134      LL
4     127      KK
0      99      QA
1      65      CD
6       1      AA
5     Q23      MM
3     N12      OO
8      K9      MA
7     A10      KL
```